# Can I override the params in config file by reading a data file?

Tags: bash, shell, protractor

I have written a shell script(test.sh) to run my test suite(to override login params and url defined in config.js), which reads something like this.

```
! /bin/bash

webdriver-manager start &
webdriver_pid=$!

protractor config.js --baseUrl=${URL} --params.login.userName=${admin} --params.login.userPassword=${passd} --params.login.nonAdminUser=${userid} --params.login.nonAdminPasswd={pwd}
```

But here I expose my user id and password. Instead I want to define the user credential in a data file(e.g data.properties) and pass it to the shell script. 
now test.sh will have

```
"protractor config.js --baseUrl=${URL} . $fileName"
```

and I run the shell script like following

```
$ bash test.sh data.properties
```

This is not working.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://moduscreate.com/blog/protractor_parameters_adding_flexibility_automation_tests/) article, you can write the following into the config:

```
module.exports = {
  params: {
    baseUrl: 'url'
  },
    //  * other config options *
}
```

And run protractor like this, to override the parameter:

```
protractor conf.js --params.baseUrl='newUrl'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that

1. The variable fileName is getting set to the value you pass on your
   script's command line.
2. The file contains single line with all the
   "--params.login.blah=blah" arguments.

If those assumptions are true, you should be able to do:

```
protractor config.js --baseUrl=${URL} $(cat ${fileName})
```